# Access query to currency

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am have been trying to convert results in a list box to currency.

Usually I would use:

```
format([Field]),"currency")
```

This didn't work and tried for a while, so I used a quick fix of:

```
"£" & sum([Field])
```

In the short term this gives me what I want, however this causes the **£** to show even if they didn't log in to the system yesterday. So If nothing is found I need it to just show as blank, I thought the following would work but didn't:

```
NZ("£" & sum([Field]),"")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use CCur:

```
Amount: CCur([Field])
```

Then format this as you like when displaying.

If the format is your issue, try:

```
Format(Sum([Field]),"£ 0.00;£ -0.00;;;")
```

Comment: Like this? CCur(Sum([tbl_cash_yesterday.Total Amount]))    - This brings back an error that the expression is type incorrectly

Comment: I worked it out just before your reply. Thank you for the help

Comment: You can also try to control formatting using the format property of the field or text box. This has the advantage that the underlying value still is a number, instead of it being a string.